# How do i check whether the selected day is monday or not using loop concepts in a calendar?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= Totaldays; i++)
    {
        var d = new DateTime(dtime1.Year, dtime1.Month, i);

        if (d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
        {
            Response.Write(d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")+"</br>");
        }

    }
```

I need to use loop concepts instead of DayOfWeek method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all mondays of current mounth you can use this method:

```
    public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetThisMonthMondaysTimes()
    {
        int daysToMonday = (int) DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek - 1;
        DateTime nearestMonday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(daysToMonday);
        for (DateTime day = nearestMonday; day.Month == nearestMonday.Month; day = day.AddDays(7))
            yield return day;
    }
```

Comment: I have to use for loop iteration. I cant use this method because I am a beginner in .NET.